# Designer throws exception when I use ObjectDataProvider and set Type property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I try to use `ObjectDataProvider` and set type using Type property:

```
   xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
   xmlns:eng="clr-namespace:ViKing.Engine;assembly=ViKing.Engine"
   ...    
   <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="proxyTypes" 
                        MethodName="GetValues"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type Type="{x:Type eng:ProxyTypes}" />
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
```

WPF designer refuses to load with following exception:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: typeName
```

It looks like designer expects TypeName property to be set. But I don't know how to correctly set it. I tried to use full type name ViKing.Engine.ProxyTypes but no luck there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. Type tag should look like this:

```
<x:Type TypeName="eng:ProxyTypes" />
```